# Run MS-SQL script file in Java or Scala

Tags: java, sql-server, scala

I have list of .sql files in my repository, when these files are executed all my DB data and code will be created. I would like to check if there is any tailored java or scala solution to run these .sql files. Please help if someone is aware of this.
I can use jdbc but noticed I have to remove "GO" statements after reading file data into buffer.

***someSQLScript.sql***

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE column1 = 'xxxxx'
AND  column2 = 'x'
GO

insert into myTable (column1, column2,column3)
values ('xxxxx', 'x', 'NAGA')
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use 3rd party libraries for DB migration. In your case it can be `Flyway`.

It supports MS SQL `GO` statements, please check documentation  [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/sqlserver)

And you can invoke these SQL migration scripts directly from [Java source code](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/). To get started with this, please refer to this [documentation](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/firststeps/api)